# add condition in Order by in CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I am quering a sharepoint list using CAML query. Here i am using Order by condition on one list column. There is a chance of having null values in order column, at this scenario I want to Order the list using another list column (ex: Title column'). How to add this Order by condition in caml query to fetch the sharepoint list items.

My Code is:

```
 query.ViewXml = "<View><Query>";
 query.ViewXml += "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + orderBy + "'/></OrderBy>";

 query.ViewXml += "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + fieldRef + "'/><Value Type = '" + type + "'>" + value + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            query.ViewXml += "</Query></View>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple fields in the OrderBy-section:

```
"<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + orderBy + "'/><FieldRef Name='" + orderBySecondary + "'/></OrderBy>"
```

This will be equivalent to: Order by 'orderBy' Then By 'orderBySecondary'

Comment: My requirement is not like that. If 'order by' column does not have any values then I have to sort the list based on 'orderBySecondary' column. I dontwant to use both columns as sorting columns.

Comment: So you mean that for some items the column will be empty and some it will not? In that case you need to sort it manually using C#.

Comment: Since you are building up your CAML in a C# class, you only need to do an "if (orderBy==null)", then do some magical code. I mean, just add an if block and thats it. The line where you are creating your "OrderBy" clause, is the one you need to put into that block. In the other hand, get all the items, then do some linq magic and done, but  it would be not that much efficient.